# Update table failure without any error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

I'm current facing a strange issue that everytime i want to update my table value field from **reserved** to **cancelled**.

every time i click the button it din't pop any error but when i went to my ms-access to check it never change...

My Method:

```
    public static void CancelClasses(int rid, int mid)
    {
        OleDbConnection myconnection = GetConnection();
        string mysql = "UPDATE ClassesReservation SET Status = 'cancelled' WHERE ReservationID= "+rid+" AND MID="+mid+";";
        OleDbCommand mycmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, myconnection);
        try
        {
            myconnection.Open();
            mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            myconnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Button Function:

```
    protected void CancelWS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox3.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Invalid Submit! Please select an Class or Workshop";
        }
        else
        {
            int reid = int.Parse(ListBox3.SelectedValue);
            int MID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["memberid"]);

            DBconn.CancelClasses(reid, MID);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not concatenate strings - it is susceptible for SQL Injection attacks. Use Parameterized Queries instead

Comment: Also, `mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns the number of records affected, so if it's greater than zero, it worked.  Make sure you aren't looking at a copied database.

Comment: Grr think that the ids are guids, anyway parametrize your queries.

Comment: other than sql injection issue, do you think is there something wrong with my method?

Comment: You tell us.  What value is ExecuteNonQuery returning?

Comment: Try getting the complete string while debugging, for the variable, string mysql, and run that exact query against your DB[Directly in your DB] and let us know the result.

Comment: I would check string conection to make sure you are pointing the right db.

Comment: @LarsTech how do i use ExecuteNonQuery() to debug this? New to c# not really understanding how to debug

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza checked is pointing to right db

Comment: try `int numRows = mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza sorry.. i'm new to this.. still no idea how to do that debug

Comment: well you have to learn. Google `Debug Visual Studio`, here is something I found in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHnxx99DudI